# Variable and constant with the same name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, variables, naming-conventions

If I execute the following code in python on CPython interpreter, it works as expected:

```
A = 1
a = 2
print(A)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

The question is will this behavior persist with other implementations of Python interpreters? Can I rely on this and produce such a code?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: 'systems that consider different case of the same letter to be the same' - which system would that be, and what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: are you thinking of Windows file-paths, which are case-insensitive? That's not at all relevant to Python code: Python variables are always case sensitive, and the underlying operating system the code is running on is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, this will work on all systems.  The python interpreter is case-sensitive, regardless of the platform.

Comment: `A != a`.  Python interpreter is case sensitive.  These are two different objects.

Comment: Where can I read more about how Python interprets this? Is this requirement specified somewhere that all interpreters would treat it the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These effectively are just two different variables, so I would imagine that this behaviour will persist in all systems.

By convention, constants are upper-case. However, Python is seeing two completely different variables, as it's a case-sensitive language.

Not entirely sure if relevent, but see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) for naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Re names: I used A and a just as an example, of course.